# C++ Memory Leak on function argument

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

So i will get straight to the point: I have a function that is adding some stuff (which happens to be a class) to another class:

```
tower->set_weapon(new NoWeapon());
```

The set_weapon() is a simple method in the tower class, which associated a inner variable with this new NoWeapon class it receives.

```
virtual void set_weapon(Weapon* weapon){ weapon_ = weapon; };
```

weapon_ is a pointer to the Weapon class, and NoWeapon is hierarchically the son of weapon. When everything is said and done, the tower itself cleans everything up:

```
weapon_->Clean();
delete weapon_;
```

However, im still getting a memory leak. Im using vld on VisualStudio 2013, and it detects a memory leak on the first line i mentioned

```
tower->set_weapon(new NoWeapon());
```

Any idea why this is happening and how could i work around it?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Thanks to YSC for the solution. I was in fact getting a leak over not initializing the original weapon pointer, but your ideas got me back on track.

As for the unique_ptr ideas, i played with it before, but it wasn't the solution i was looking for. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: provide definition for noWeapon and Weapon.

Comment: Perhaps you're calling set_weapon() more than once, the code here  forgot to dispose the previous weapon for such a case.

Comment: Just guessing given the amount of code you've provided, but this could happen if you call `set_weapon` twice; the first weapon would never get deleted.

Comment: My ESP tells me that you later call `set_weapon` to replace the pointer with a pointer to a new weapon, leaking the original `NoWeapon` object. *Why are you using raw pointers?*

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, what's ESP?

Comment: @SergeyA Information gained through a source other than the normal senses. In this case, by reading the OP's mind.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, i got the meaning alright. :) I was asking for formal disambiguation.

Comment: Use smart pointers to avoid this

Comment: unique_ptr is not a "good idea". It's the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We lack context information, but basically if `Tower::set_weapon()` is called twice, `Tower::weapon_` get overwritten and memory leaks. Suggestion:

```
Tower::Tower()
    : weapon_(nullptr)
{}

void Tower::set_weapon(Weapon* weapon)
{
    if (weapon_ != nullptr)
    {
        weapon_->Clean(); // should be called by Weapon::~Weapon()
    }
    delete weapon_;
    weapon_ = weapon;
};
```

You could also use an `std::unique_ptr`:

```
class Tower
{
    std::unique_ptr<Weapon> weapon_;

public:
    Tower::Tower() {}

    void set_weapon(std::unique_ptr<Weapon> weapon)
    {
        // assume Weapon::~Weapon() is fixed
        weapon_ = std::move(weapon);
    };
};
```

Comment: and pass a unique_ptr rather than a raw pointer in the method!

Comment: Using `unique_ptr` also avoid copying problems (Rule of Three).

Comment: In addition to using a unique_ptr, invoking Clean in the destructor might lead to a lot less problems (invoking methods on nullptr, copy paste of code whenever a weapon is destroyed, etc.)

Comment: weapon_ = std::move(weapon); // ;-)

Comment: @RichardHodges friday evenings are so cruel! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

note: YSC's answer is correct. A weapon *should* not need a `Clean` method as it can handle resource deallocation in a destructor.

However, if there really is some reason for the call to `Clean`, you can encapsulate all this in `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter.

like so:

```
struct weapon_cleaner
{
  void operator()(Weapon* pw) const nothrow {
    if (pw) {
      try {
        pw->Clean();
      }
      catch(...) {
      }
    }
    delete pw;
  }
};

using weapon_pointer = std::unique_ptr<Weapon, weapon_cleaner>;

class Tower
{
    weapon_pointer weapon_;

public:
    Tower::Tower() {}

    void set_weapon(weapon_pointer weapon)
    {
        weapon_ = std::move(weapon);
    };
};
```

called like so:

```
weapon_pointer make_machine_gun() {
  return weapon_pointer(new MachineGun(), 
                        weapon_cleaner());
}

mytower.set_weapon(make_machine_gun());
```